# How to enable primary index for a bucket in couchbase using python SDK?

Tags: python, couchbase

I'm new to couchbase and am trying to query documents in an existing bucket. When I execute my server code in python, the following error log is reported

```
HTTPError: <RC=0x3B[HTTP Operation failed. Inspect status code for details], HTTP Request failed. Examine 'objextra' for full result, Results=1, C Source=(src/http.c,140), OBJ=ViewResult<rc=0x3B[HTTP Operation failed. Inspect status code for details], value={u'status': u'fatal', u'metrics': {u'elapsedTime': u'64.108808ms', u'executionTime': u'63.940999ms', u'resultSize': 0, u'resultCount': 0, u'errorCount': 1}, u'errors': [{u'msg': u'No primary index on keyspace default. Use CREATE PRIMARY INDEX to create one.', u'code': 4000}], u'requestID': u'14a2ba49-512b-4a4b-9e8d-37ef6c010c34'}, http_status=404>>
```

My current python snippet which performs the get request/query operation is

```
 def get(self):
        tableName = request.args.get("tablename")

        createPrimaryIndex = N1QLQuery("create primary index on `default`")
        cb.n1ql_query(createPrimaryIndex)

        q = N1QLQuery("select * from `default` where tablename='{0}' limit 10;".format(tablename))
        for row in cb.n1ql_query(q):
            print row
```

I have observed that if I go into the couchbase console and execute the query `set primary index on default` (instead of doing it inside my server code), and then execute my server code, the data is returned fine. However, I'm looking to execute this query within my server code. Is this possible and if so how should I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `n1ql_index_create` with `defer` set to `False` (which is default), or set it to `True` and use combination of `build_deferred_indexes`/`watch_indexes` to detect the moment when index has been created.

https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-python-client/blob/2.2.5/couchbase/bucketmanager.py#L355